# simple integration artimethic error

Tags: calculus, arithmetic, fractions

I am trying to integrate a polynomial but I couldn't get the correct answer somehow. I feel like I'm making a mistake when evaluating the integral.

$$\pi\int_{-1}^1{1-2x^2+x^4}dx=[{x-{2x^3\over3}+{x^5\over5}}]^1_{-1}$$
$$=1-\frac23+\frac15+1-\frac23+\frac15$$
$$=2+{2(-2)\over3}+{2(1)\over5}$$
$$={30-26\over15}=\frac4{15}\pi$$

But the integral calculator is giving me: $\frac{16}{15}\pi$

Comment: Check your fraction arithmetic! It should be $\dfrac{30-20+6}{15}$. Also, you dropped out the factor $\pi$ and it mysteriously reappeared in the end.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen thank you..yep... `-20+6 = -14` not  `-26`

Comment: Slow down; you move too fast.  Haste makes waste.  (etc.) If you're trying to track down an arithmetic error, you're shooting yourself in the foot when you go directly from $2+{{2(-2)}\over3}+{{2(1)}\over5}$  to  ${30-26}\over{15}$ all in one step.  By not showing where the $26$ came from, you deprive yourself of the opportunity to see that it's wrong.

Comment: You also left out the $\pi$ in several places, which costs marks on tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\left.\left(x-\frac23x^3+\frac15x^5\right)\right|_{-1}^1=1-(-1)-\frac23(1-(-1))+\frac15(1-(-1))=$$

$$=2-\frac43+\frac25=\frac{30-20+6}{15}=\frac{16}{15}$$

You can avoid a lot of these problems *in cases like this* if you use the property

$$\int_{-a}^af(x)dx=2\int_0^af(x)dx\;,\;\;\;a>0\;,\;\;f(x)\;\;\text{an even function,}$$

so in this case we'd get

$$2\int_0^1(1-2x^2+x^4)dx=2\left[x-\frac23x^3+\frac15x^5\right]_0^1=$$

$$=2\left(1-\frac23+\frac15\right)=2\frac{15-10+3}{15}=2\frac8{15}=\frac{16}{15}$$